# Integrating Flex with CakePHP

Tags: apache-flex, cakephp, integration, flexbuilder

I have a CakePHP 1.3 project. I want to integrate some small portion that is done by Flex. How can I use controller of CakePHP or how can I use the Flex as a view?

Which plugins are required for total integration of CakePHP and Flex and how do I install them?

Answer (score 0):

I am not fimilar with PHP, normaly we embed SWF in JSPs, ASPs, and HTML, and think same for PHP, and found this article about FLEX+CakePHP

[Flex remoting with cakePHP - CpAmf plugin](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/vernerd/2009/06/28/flex-remoting-with-cakephp-cpamf-plugin-1)

Hopes that helps

Comment: Thanx for ur answer. I tried this link before but could not understand or could not implement. Is there anybody who is expert in both cakphp and flex? plz explain step by step what should i do for integrating flex with cakephp.